# Trimming a string in c++ using macro

Tags: c++

Here is an example of what I try to do:

Extract a string `HELLOrs` from `HELLO_EXTRArs` using macro in c++
Similarly, `HIDUDE` from `HI_EXTRADUDE`

So, basically I want to remove the string `_EXTRA` using macro.
Is this possible?

Comment: Only macros? what with `template meta-programming`?

Comment: The most important question: **Why?**

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
std::string yourString = "something with _EXTRA";
std::string strToRemove = "_EXTRA";
size_t a = yourString.find(strToRemove);

if (a < yourString.length()) //if strToRemove is found in yourString
   yourString.erase(a, strToRemove.length());
```

Comment: Why every answer use `replace` instead of [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) method to remove a substring ?

Comment: @Garf365 Thanks for pointing that out. Yes if you just want to remove a substring this is better.

Answer (score -3):

This will do the job for you,

```
#define removestr "_EXTRA"
```

use this below code to replace,

```
string.replace(string.find(removestr),sizeof(removestr)-1,"");
```

where string is "HI_EXTRADUDE" or any string value containing "_EXTRA"